# Executible Jar File on one computer, JAR File on a second

Tags: executable-jar

I seem to be having trouble with a JAR file losing its ability to be executable.
The executable JAR file is located on a server, from my PC in the office, the JAR reads its type as an "Executable Jar File", however on a clients laptop, the file type reads as "JAR File".

Am I missing a setting somewhere that will correct this mistake?
Both my PC and the clients are running the latest version of JRE.

I'm at my whits end as I've been stuck on this problem for about 3 days.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: If it's the same file, then it is executable on both computers. It does not matter how the file type is displayed (where? what application/OS?). It could be missing "execute" permissions on the file system level. Have you tried running it? If so, how, and what happened?

Comment: When I tried to run it, the process appears in task manager for a second and then disappears.
No error message, or anything.

Comment: Oh appologies, I'm still at work and didn't read the comment properly.
In the file properties, under details is where I am reading the file type. The systems are Windows 7.

The file is located on one of the businesses servers, so it is something to do with the client as the application runs fine on my computer, and there are no other reports of this happening elsewhere.
How would I check to see if it is missing the "execute" permission?

Comment: "the process appears in task manager for a second and then disappears". Can you run it from a command prompt ( `java -jar abc.jar` ) to see if you get any error messages?

Comment: Indeed, I have been able to run it via command prompt and batch file using 
`java -Xmx512m -jar Application.jar`

At first, it was set to use 1024mb, but I decided to rule out memory issue so I brought that down.